# Why spacy morphologizer doesn't work when we use a custom tokenizer?

Tags: spacy, spacy-3

I don't understand why when i'm doing this

```py
import spacy
from copy import deepcopy
nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_lg")

class MyTokenizer:
    def __init__(self, tokenizer):
        self.tokenizer = deepcopy(tokenizer)
    def __call__(self, text):
        return self.tokenizer(text)

nlp.tokenizer = MyTokenizer(nlp.tokenizer)
doc = nlp("Un texte en français.")
```

Tokens don't have any morph assigned

```py
print([tok.morph for tok in doc])
> ['','','','','']
```

Is this behavior expected? If yes, why ? (spacy v3.0.7)

Comment: I don't know why that would happen, and I can't reproduce this in 3.2.0.

Comment: Note that if you have an actual different tokenizer, the morphologizer could do something like this for tokens it's never seen because tokenization changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipeline expects `nlp.vocab` and `nlp.tokenizer.vocab` to refer to the exact same `Vocab` object, which isn't the case after running `deepcopy`.

I admit that I'm not entirely sure off the top of my head why you end up with empty analyses instead of more specific errors, but I think the `MorphAnalysis` objects, which are stored centrally in the vocab in `vocab.morphology`, end up out-of-sync between the two vocabs.